# Cant run code from imported file

Tags: python, import

How can I run a function I have created in another file? I know there are many questions asking this but my code is so simple I dont get how it doesn't work.

In one file called Testfile I have

```
def greeting():
    print("Hello")
```

and in the other I have

```
import Testfile

greeting()
```

but when I run the code I get the error 
"name 'greeting' is not defined"

Comment: Use either "from Testfile import greeting" or prefix greeting with Testfile.

Comment: Use `Testfile.greeting()`.

Comment: That gives me the error - 'module' object has no attribute 'greeting'

Comment: So `greeting` isn't in `Testfile`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Testfile    
Testfile.greeting()
```

or

```
from Testfile import greeting
greeting()
```

you have to specify which module the function is coming from with a `.` or you tell it when you are importing.

Comment: when I use from Testfile import greetings, I get "cannot import name 'greeting'"

Comment: but you can `import Testfile` just fine ?

Comment: yes, when I use the method - Testfile.greeting() I get the error 'module' object has no attribute 'greeting'

Comment: Where is this module 'Testfile' stored? is it in the same folder as your python file? if not you will have to append or insert to `sys.path` where ever Testfile is. Are you sure it's called `greeting` and `Testfile.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You must call the function after the module that contains it:

```
    import Testfile
    Testfile.greeting()
```

Note that this approach is better because this may lead to namespace conflicts and prevents the scalability of your program.

Please follow [PEP 8, section module names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)